# How to model logical/boolean expressions in XML efficiently?

Tags: xml, boolean-logic

Little xml modeling exercise here.

Let's say we have some logical expression: 
   (x & y) | (p & q)

and it needs to be expressed in XML for whatever reason.

Here is a quick stab, but I think this is clumsy:

```
 <expr>
    <or>
        <and>
            <e>x</e>
            <e>y</e>
        </and>
        <and>
            <e>p</e>
            <e>q</e>
        </and>
    </or>
 </expr>
```

Another stab, which doesn't smell right to me:

```
<expr>
    <or>
        <and l="x" r="y"/>
        <and l="p" r="q"/>
    </or>
</expr>
```

How would you go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Armatus answer looks good to me. I consider the left and right element as redundant. Having a logical expression it doesn't matter if i evaluate them left right or right left.

```
 <expr type="or">
    <expr type="and">
        <sig>x</sig>
        <sig>y</sig>
    </expr>
    <expr type="and">
        <sig>p</sig>
        <sig>q</sig>
    </expr>
</expr>
```

for example:
  `(x & y) | (p & q)` is the same as `(q & p) | (y & x)`

furthermore its possible to add more than just two signals.

Comment: For `>` or `<` left and right *would* be important. IMHO being able to "group" more than one signal is a nice convenience feature, but they would still have to be processed two at a time.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
<expr:or>
<l>
    <expr:and>
    <l>x</l><r>y</r>
    </expr>
</l>
<r>
    <expr:and>
    <l>p</l><r>q</r>
    </expr>
</r>
</expr>
```

Could also add `<expr:xor><l>x</l><r>y</r></expr>` and `<expr:not>x</expr>`.

Comment: that is nicely consistent and nestable.

Comment: Instead of the `:` you could also use a `type` attribute (`type="or"` etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Your first "quick stab" looks perfectly reasonable to me, except perhaps for the outer 'expr' element, which doesn't add much value.

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting to look at how expression trees are modeled in Microsoft .NET's [System.Linq.Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) namespace. The basic concept that I think is important here, is that everything inherits from the basic [Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2) class – so pretty much everything is an expression, be it a binary operation, a parameter, a constant, .. etc.

Furthermore, the NuGet package [Serialize.Linq](https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq) demonstrates how such expression trees could be serialized to XML for example.

**Long solution**

That's just for reference though. I think the XML model can be made even simpler. I would model your example like this:

```
<expr returns="boolean">
  <params>
    <param name="x" type="boolean">
    <param name="y" type="boolean">
    <param name="p" type="boolean">
    <param name="q" type="boolean">
  </params>
  <body op="bor">
    <left op="band">
      <left  op="param">x</left>
      <right op="param">y</left>
    </left>
    <right op="band">
      <left  op="param">p</left>
      <right op="param">q</left>
    </right>
  </body>
<expr>
```

**Short solution**

Depending on your implementation, you might be able to omit the `<params>` element and `type` attributes and handle those things in a more "implicit" way when interpreting the expression (kind of like JavaScript, PowerShell, ...). Also, you could make the element and type names shorter, if the size/length of the XML output is an issue.

So, here is a and example of a highly shortened version:

```
<e t="bor">
  <l t="band">
    <l t="prm">x</l>
    <r t="prm">y</r>
  </l>
  <r t="band">
    <l t="prm">p</l>
    <r t="prm">y</r>
  </r>
</e>
```

**Another example**

For the sake of completeness, here another example of how a more complex expression would be modeled in such a way.

Pseudo code lambda/arrow expression:

```
(float b, int e) => e == 0 ? 1 : (e == 1 ? b : pow(b, e))
```

XML representation:

```
<expr returns="float">
 <params>
   <prm name="b" type="float" />
   <prm name="e" type="int" />
 </params>
 <body op="if">
   <cond op="eq">
     <left op="param">e</left>
     <right op="const" type="int">0</right>
   </cond>
   <true op="const" type="float">1</true>
   <false op="if">
     <cond op="eq">
       <left op="param">e</left>
       <right op="const" type="int">1</right>
     </cond>
     <true op="param">b</true>
     <false op="call" name="pow">
       <args>
         <arg op="param">p</arg>
         <arg op="param">e</arg>
       </args>
     </false>
   </false>
 </body>
</expr>
```